# How do I get Lookup type related lists to display when using apex:detail?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a Custom Object with related lists, two of which are Master Detail type, the others Lookup type. I've configured the Custom Object page to display all these related lists and when viewing this object using baseUrl/Id all the lists display fine.

When displaying this Custom Object through a VisualForce page using the apex:detail tag only the Master Detail lists show.

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:detail subject="{!'a0I8A00000552ot'}" relatedList="true" /> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Is there a way to get the Lookup lists to show also?

Answer (score 0):

Might be permissions issue. Does user have "Read" right to the objects on related list? If not - they might not show at all. If he has "Read" to object but none of actual records (sharing rules etc) - the list should display but empty.

You view it as yourself or as another user? Which lists and in what order are shown will be controlled by page layout. So if you have different layout assigned to this user's profile or you view 2 different records (do you have record types?) - yep, it's possible that on the other layout only 2 lists are shown.

What happens if you force add to VF page something like `<apex:relatedList subject="a0I8A00000552ot" list="CustomObjects__r" />` (use proper relationship name)

Comment: HI eyescream, thanks for those suggestions. I'm sure it's not related to rights and profiles. The relatedList tag is not playing ball either but most likely the list value wrong. I would have expected it to be TestObjects__r as that is the child relationship name but getting error 'TestObjects__r' is not a valid child relationship name for entity ParentObject

Comment: You could inspect Setup -> API -> Enterprise WSDL for the right relationship name (it's bit rubbish to find, it'll be like in Account element there's `<element name="Cases" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>`). Or go to https://workbench.developerforce.com/describe.php and view child relationships? Or run piece of code similar to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/23507/799